# Jetpack Compose Canvas drawing order issue

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

This problem is regarding Z-Axes of elements inside `Canvas` in Jetpack Compose. I have troubles to figure out how to stack elements. I know they stack one over other as they are being drawn, like in example below:

```
Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(20.dp)) {
    val radius1 = 30f * dpi
    val radius2 = 20f * dpi
    val yStart = size.height.div(2)
    val xStart = size.width.div(2)
    drawCircle(
        color = Color.Red,
        center = Offset(
            x = xStart,
            y = yStart
        ),
        radius = radius1
    )
    drawCircle(
        color = Color.Green,
        center = Offset(
            x = xStart,
            y = yStart
        ),
        radius = radius2
    )
}
```

So we get this result:   [image]

In the next step I get an event in my code that needs to move green circle behind red circle. [image]

**NOTE: I know I can just make a method to replace order of what circle is being draw first with some if statement. But my real life example is very complex with a lot of different draw composable interacting.**

Is there a way to set some kind of elevation for every `drawCircle` so I can stack them in app runtime, depending of my final code result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of two ways to do it:

1. You can create a enum for each item. Generically it can be any information which can be placed in a list - `enum`, `data class`, etc:

   ```
   enum class CanvasItem {
       RedCircle,
       GreenCircle,
   }

   val canvasItems = listOf(
       CanvasItem.GreenCircle,
       CanvasItem.RedCircle,
   )
   Canvas(modifier = Modifier) {
       canvasItems.forEach {
           when (it) {
               CanvasItem.GreenCircle -> {
                   drawCircle(
                       color = Color.Green,
                       // ...
                   )
               }
               CanvasItem.RedCircle -> {
                   drawCircle(
                       color = Color.Red,
                       // ...
                   )
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Drawing each figure in a separate `Canvas`, placing all of them in a `Box` and applying `Modifier.zIndex` to control order:

   ```
   Box {
       val modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(20.dp)
       Canvas(
           modifier = modifier
               .zIndex(2f)
       ) {
           drawCircle(
               color = Color.Green,
               // ...
           )
       }
       Canvas(
           modifier = modifier
               .zIndex(1f)
       ) {
           drawCircle(
               color = Color.Green,
               // ...
           )
           drawCircle(
               color = Color.Red,
               // ...
           )
       }
   }
   ```